# unable to read the registry key - nsis

Tags: nsis

i need to read the registry key from the HKLM. Even though the key(ObjectDirectories) is present in the registry, but I was unable to get the data

Here is the following code:

```
!include x64.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section

SetRegView 64

        ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" "ObjectDirectories"

        MessageBox MB_OK "The value of the ObjectDirectories : $0"

 SectionEnd
```

I've tried with `setregview32` & `setregview64`, still i was getting nothing

Comment: What does Process Monitor say?

Comment: in the message box i was getting empty - Anders, Because this key is related to "REG_MULTI_SZ" so i was unable to find the key from ReadRegStr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing the massive research, found this solution.
The key I was searching for is "REG_MULTI_SZ" to read this key, we required the set of inbuilt function. & here is the solution link.
"https://nsis.sourceforge.io/REG_MULTI_SZ_Reader"